# gravity forms api get_entries filter with created by id

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

This seems like an extremely simple question, but no matter how I slice it, I need to get data entered by manager and it's employees. Like Manager A added 5 locations, than I want to get those 5 locations and show them in first case. Second, I want to display all records (added by Employee) related to Manager A. Like Employee x, y and z entered records with different locations(added by A) I want to display those records if I select Manager A in dropdown...
I can do that with SQL like,

```
SELECT id FROM _gf_entry where created_by = (ID of Manager A)
```

->Manager is role in wordpress that I added.
than, get all data by `SELECT * FROM _gf_entry_meta where entry_id in (SELECT id FROM _gf_entry where created_by = (ID of Manager A))`

but I think there should be easy way to do this with gravity form api as it gives manageable results.

Comment: The [`GFAPI::get_entry_ids()`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/searching-and-getting-entries-with-the-gfapi/) allows you to search for specific `created_by` IDs; see the **Field Filters** under the [**Search Arguments** section](https://docs.gravityforms.com/searching-and-getting-entries-with-the-gfapi/#search-arguments) for an example.

Comment: That won't help the OP get the entry data from the query, they didn't state they wanted only ID in return.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using the Gravity Forms API in WordPress to filter entries created by a specific user (Manager A) and retrieve associated data entries.

1. **Get Manager A's User ID:**

   First, you need to get the User ID of Manager A. You can do this programmatically in WordPress. Let's assume you have Manager A's User ID stored in a variable called `$manager_id`.
2. **Query Gravity Forms Entries:**

   You can use the `GFAPI::get_entries` function to retrieve entries that meet your criteria. In your case, you want to filter entries created by Manager A. Here's an example of how to do this:

   ```php
   $entries = GFAPI::get_entries(
       array(
           'form_id' => 1, // Replace with your form ID
           'created_by' => $manager_id,
       )
   );
   ```

   Replace `1` with the actual ID of your Gravity Form.
3. **Retrieve Associated Data Entries:**

   Now that you have the entries created by Manager A, you can loop through them and retrieve associated data entries using the `_gf_entry_meta` table. Here's how you can do it:

   ```php
   $all_related_entries = array();

   foreach ($entries as $entry) {
       $entry_id = $entry['id'];

       // Query the _gf_entry_meta table to get associated data
       $data_entries = $wpdb->get_results(
           $wpdb->prepare(
               "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gf_entry_meta WHERE entry_id = %d",
               $entry_id
           ),
           ARRAY_A
       );

       // Add data entries to the result array
       $all_related_entries = array_merge($all_related_entries, $data_entries);
   }
   ```

   Make sure you have global access to the `$wpdb` object to run database queries.
4. **Display the Results:**

   Now you have the entries and associated data entries in the `$all_related_entries` array. You can loop through this array and display the results as needed.

   ```php
   foreach ($all_related_entries as $data_entry) {
       // Display the data as per your requirements
       // For example: echo $data_entry['your_field_name'];
   }
   ```

   Replace `'your_field_name'` with the actual field name you want to display.
5. **Dropdown Selection:**

   If you want to dynamically select Manager A from a dropdown, you can use a dropdown field in your Gravity Form. Then, you can modify the `$manager_id` variable based on the selected option.

This code should help you retrieve and display entries and associated data entries created by Manager A using the Gravity Forms API. Make sure to replace placeholders with actual values, and adjust the code to fit your specific form and field names. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am still getting all entries. It should fetch only entries with created by Id..

Answer (score 0):

@dharmik I think what you are wanting is something like this:

```
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $search_criteria = array(
    'field_filters' => array( //which fields to search
      array(
        'key' => 'created_by', 'value' => $user_id, // Current logged in user
        // ... Add more keys/values if needed
      )
    )
  );
  $sorting         = array();
  $paging          = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 999 );
  $subform_entries = GFAPI::get_entries( 20, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging );
```

The `get_entries` is looking for `field_filters`. In you case it's `created_by`